pkexec authentication for non-"root" sudoer
Ok so perhaps the basis of this question comes from my negligent understanding of a super user but here goes:
I have a user that is on the sudoer list, call them user1. I can switch to this user and run commands with sudo using the password for user1. I do not, however, know the password for the user root (who is inherently on the sudoer list). I would like to be able to run pkexec in a way that requests the authentication credentials for user1 (not root). MY understanding is that the --user flag for pkexec is to run the command as that user (not request auth credentials for that user).
So, how can I have pkexec request authentication credentials for user1?

when you're already root, you can switch users to user1 using the su command.

@MarcusMüller I am never able to be root user. I can only ever be user1 (which has "root" privileges)

you're wrong about that! When user1 uses sudo, the program it starts is run as root! There's no separate "root privileges" to get – the process is literally run as root. You can test that – run whoami as your normal user, then sudo whoami.

@MarcusMüller hmmm ok then there goes my theory. Let me ask you this then: why do my credentials for user1 fail in the pkexec prompt?

as which user are you running pkexec when they fail? As root user through sudo, or as user1?

@MarcusMüller as user1 I am running pkexec <application> and then I attempt to use my passwd for user1

I think it depends what polkit.addAdminRule functions your distro provides (in particular, whether there is a rule like return ["unix-group:sudo"] versus return ["unix-user:root"]. See for example Polkit - Administrator identities

@steeldriver polkit.addAdminRule(function(action, subject) {     return ["unix-group:wheel"]; }); is the only entry in 50-default.rules (which I am told I should not edit directly because edits will not persist through update). How would I create a manually a valid rule that will persist an update?

@SterlingButters I think the appropriate location for custom drop-in files would be /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/ but this is really outside my wheelhouse :) I guess the other option would be to add your user to the wheel group so that it matches your distro's default ruleset.
